# Deepin not booting!

Tags: linux, deepin

I just installed Linux Deepin.  I started the driver installation and selected the "nvida-driver" and "intel-micro-code". When they where finished, I tried to reboot. I first tried the logout feature, then I logged back in and pressed the lock button. Then I was greeted with a black terminal window with a blinking underscore.

I next tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to reboot the computer, and then when it booted again I got greeted with the same blinking underscore. I was thinking that maybe it took some time to boot.
I checked back maybe 20 minutes later and the underscore was still there.

How do I get the normal desktop back? I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login with root in text mode.

Comment: @Fox After Pressing Ctrl + Alt + Del I got a Deepin thing. So i think it rebooted fine!

Comment: @Fox Does the same As Ctrl + Alt + Del

Comment: @Fox It say like. That i dont have any screens connected and that The Connection was Refused.

Comment: Pic of it : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B30nfNvLAotxaFJsWkFxVThxWlk

Comment: Managed To Fix it by useing a script if found that removed my drivers
 
Source : http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nv
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
# Had to add : sudo apt install xserver-xorg; My self. Was not in script
sudo apt install xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

Comment: Is there a way off getting working drivers on deepin?

Answer (score 1):

Once you enter the Grub menu, *select* (but don't enter) Deepin, then press the letter *E* on your keyboard. Replace *quiet splash* with *nomodeset*.

Also in case you use Deepin 15.4 Beta, there is currently a horrible bug with th updated version of libdtk* packages. Don't upgrade the system, if you are on 15.4 Beta.

Comment: I Found splash quiet and not quiet splash on the end of a line and replaced that with nomodeset and that just removed the deepin flowing water animation thing. It did not fix it!

Comment: Then you either removed all graphics drivers an replaced it with nvidia's or you did something additional to let the system stop booting. Because if you put in the *nomodeset* parameter, the newly installed *nvidia* driver won't be loaded and everything should work as it did before.